# Generating a model referencing self column name error

Tags: phoenix-framework, ecto

Given (from scratch )

```
mix phoenix.new sandpit
mix ecto.create
mix phoenix.gen.json Part parts name part_of:references:parts
mix ecto.migrate
```

and editing the route so

```
scope "/api", Sandpit do
    pipe_through :api
    resources "/parts", PartController, except: [:new, :edit]
  end
```

then running the server and going to

```
http://localhost:4000/api/parts
```

I get the errors

```
info] Running Sandpit.Endpoint with Cowboy using http on port 4000
13 Jul 23:11:37 - info: compiled 5 files into 2 files, copied 3 in 744ms
[info] GET /api/parts
[debug] Processing by Sandpit.PartController.index/2
  Parameters: %{}
  Pipelines: [:api]
[debug] SELECT p0."id", p0."name", p0."part_of_id", p0."inserted_at", p0."updated_at" FROM "parts" AS p0 [] ERROR query=78.0ms
[info] Sent 500 in 140ms
[error] #PID<0.318.0> running Sandpit.Endpoint terminated
Server: localhost:4000 (http)
Request: GET /api/parts
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR (undefined_column): column p0.part_of_id does not exist
        (ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:185: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query!/5
```

is this a bug with the generator?  it seems to want to name things with `_id` either it seems like a hidden "rule" or it failed to add in _id.  If it doesn't auto add _id, I'd think either it would error doing the generation, or use the names as given without crashing?

Trying with

```
mix phoenix.gen.json Thing things name thing_of_id:references:things
```

and migrating causes no errors

or is something else going on?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. I think you should report it or post to their Google Groups mailing list (but first check if it's fixed in the `master` branch).

Answer (score 0):

Known issue, currently under debate on what the best solution is :-

https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/issues/1605

Current solution is to remember to suffix references with _id